# Building an image slider using HTML, CSS, and JS. How can I space out images to make one image appear in the viewport at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm building an image slider using HTML, CSS, and JS. It's running on a timer using JS and can also be scrolled through using navigation arrows when hovered over. I feel like it's almost done, but right now all the images are stuck next to each other in the viewport and I can't figure out how to space out the images so that only one shows in the viewport at a time.

I don't want the images to be 100% width, or else they'll be too big and they'll look bad (the slider is for brand logos). I just want each logo to be spaced out and centered within the viewport so there's only one logo showing at a time.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-slider">
  <div class="image-slider__viewport">
    <div class="image-slider__container">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hH1XLfK/checkout-logo-3-200x.webp" alt="eye logo" />
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Yh7J36fV/reef.webp" alt="reef logo" />
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/F13M3Wc3/manduka.webp" alt="manduka logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-slider__navigation">
      <button class="image-slider__navigation--prev">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15.75 19.5L8.25 12l7.5-7.5" />
        </svg>
      </button>
      <button class="image-slider__navigation--next">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M8.25 4.5l7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-slider {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

.image-slider__viewport {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image-slider__container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.image-slider__container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.image-slider__navigation {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

.image-slider__navigation--prev,
.image-slider__navigation--next {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-slider__navigation--prev {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.image-slider__navigation--next {
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

JS:

```
const sliderViewport = document.querySelector(
  '.image-slider__viewport'
);

const sliderImageContainer = sliderViewport.querySelector(
  '.image-slider__container'
);

const numberOfSliderImages =
  sliderImageContainer.querySelectorAll('img').length;

let slideOffset = 0;

const moveSlides = offset => {
  const imageWidth =
    sliderImageContainer.querySelector('img').offsetWidth;
  sliderImageContainer.style.transform = `translateX(-${
    offset * imageWidth
  }px)`;
};

let timer;

const setTimer = () => {
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    slideOffset =
      slideOffset < numberOfSliderImages - 1 ?
      slideOffset + 1 :
      0;
    moveSlides(slideOffset);
  }, 2000);
};

setTimer();

sliderViewport.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
});

sliderViewport.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  setTimer();
});

const prevButton = document.querySelector(
  '.image-slider__navigation--prev'
);
const nextButton = document.querySelector(
  '.image-slider__navigation--next'
);

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  slideOffset =
    slideOffset > 1 ?
    slideOffset - 1 :
    numberOfSliderImages - 1;
  moveSlides(slideOffset);
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  slideOffset =
    slideOffset < numberOfSliderImages - 1 ?
    slideOffset + 1 :
    0;
  moveSlides(slideOffset);
});
```

Here's the code for the slider. My guess is that it's a styling issue, and the CSS needs to be adjusted to make the images spaced out enough to show one at a time in the viewport. But I've tried messing around with the CSS and haven't had any success. I'm not exactly sure which part of the CSS needs to be adjusted either.

Here's a link to the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t07mxkvw/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, `image-slider__container` has the same width of `image-slider__viewport`. It means that you display all 3 images at once, and just transforming the width of image. So images are stuck.
I think this is what you want.

```js
      const sliderViewport = document.querySelector(".image-slider__viewport")

      const sliderImageContainer = sliderViewport.querySelector(
        ".image-slider__container"
      )

      const numberOfSliderImages =
        sliderImageContainer.querySelectorAll("img").length

      let slideOffset = 0

      const moveSlides = (offset) => {
        const imageWidth =
          sliderImageContainer.querySelector("img").parentElement.offsetWidth
        sliderImageContainer.style.transform = `translateX(-${
          offset * imageWidth
        }px)`
      }

      let timer

      const setTimer = () => {
        timer = setInterval(() => {
          slideOffset =
            slideOffset < numberOfSliderImages - 1 ? slideOffset + 1 : 0
          moveSlides(slideOffset)
        }, 2000)
      }

      setTimer()

      sliderViewport.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        clearInterval(timer)
      })

      sliderViewport.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        setTimer()
      })

      const prevButton = document.querySelector(
        ".image-slider__navigation--prev"
      )
      const nextButton = document.querySelector(
        ".image-slider__navigation--next"
      )

      prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        slideOffset =
          slideOffset > 1 ? slideOffset - 1 : numberOfSliderImages - 1
        moveSlides(slideOffset)
      })

      nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        slideOffset =
          slideOffset < numberOfSliderImages - 1 ? slideOffset + 1 : 0
        moveSlides(slideOffset)
      })

      const setImageSliderContainerWidth = () => {
        const sliderViewport = document.querySelector(".image-slider__viewport")
        const sliderImageContainer = sliderViewport.querySelector(
          ".image-slider__container"
        )
        const imageCount =
          sliderImageContainer.getElementsByTagName("img").length

        sliderImageContainer.style.width = `${
          sliderViewport.offsetWidth * imageCount
        }px`
      }

      window.onload = setImageSliderContainerWidth
      window.onresize = setImageSliderContainerWidth
```

```css
      .image-slider {
        width: 60%;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .image-slider__viewport {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }

      .image-slider__container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: auto;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }

      .image-slider__container div {
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
      }

      .image-slider__container img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 300px;
      }

      .image-slider__navigation {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
      }

      .image-slider__navigation--prev,
      .image-slider__navigation--next {
        position: absolute;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .image-slider__navigation--prev {
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }

      .image-slider__navigation--next {
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
```

```html
    <div class="image-slider">
      <div class="image-slider__viewport">
        <div class="image-slider__container" id="container">
          <div>
            <img
              src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hH1XLfK/checkout-logo-3-200x.webp"
              alt="eye logo"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              src="https://i.postimg.cc/Yh7J36fV/reef.webp"
              alt="reef logo"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              src="https://i.postimg.cc/F13M3Wc3/manduka.webp"
              alt="manduka logo"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hH1XLfK/checkout-logo-3-200x.webp"
              alt="eye logo"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              src="https://i.postimg.cc/Yh7J36fV/reef.webp"
              alt="reef logo"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              src="https://i.postimg.cc/F13M3Wc3/manduka.webp"
              alt="manduka logo"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-slider__navigation">
          <button class="image-slider__navigation--prev">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              stroke-width="1.5"
              stroke="currentColor"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M15.75 19.5L8.25 12l7.5-7.5"
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
          <button class="image-slider__navigation--next">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              stroke-width="1.5"
              stroke="currentColor"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M8.25 4.5l7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5"
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I added JS function to set `image-slider__container`'s width.

```
      const setImageSliderContainerWidth = () => {
        const sliderViewport = document.querySelector(".image-slider__viewport")
        const sliderImageContainer = sliderViewport.querySelector(
          ".image-slider__container"
        )
        const imageCount =
          sliderImageContainer.getElementsByTagName("img").length

        sliderImageContainer.style.width = `${
          sliderViewport.offsetWidth * imageCount
        }px`
      }
```

Comment: Looks good and works properly, but there will be more images added to the slider in the future.. what would be the best solution that can work without having to change the code/width every time an additional image is added?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I updated the answer. You can add as many images as you want without having to change the code.